# Conditionally update attributes of INPUT element before 'click' is triggered with $refs in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, capacitor

I'm updating an input element's attributes conditionally, and then firing the input's click using $refs ... all in one go from a modal.

The problem is the click was firing before the attributes have changed, so i've added a 10ms setTimeout, which has solved the problem.

Surely there is a better, more Vue way of doing this though?

The input element:

```
      <input
        ref="file"
        type="file"
        name=""
        :multiple="!androidCameraToggle"
        :capture="androidCameraToggle"
        :accept="[androidCameraToggle ? 'image/*' : 'image/*;capture=camera']"
        style="display:none"
        @change="addImage"
      >
```

Data:

```
data () {
    return {
      androidCameraToggle: false
    }
  },
```

The modal:

```
    async sourcePrompt() {
      const swalWithBootstrapButtons = this.$swal.mixin({
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary p-2',
          cancelButton: 'btn btn-primary p-2'
        }
      })
      swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
        title: 'Upload Photo',
        text: "Choose image source.",
        icon: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Camera',
        cancelButtonText: 'Photo Album'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          this.androidCameraToggle = true
          let fileInput = this.$refs.file
          setTimeout(function(){ fileInput.click()}, 10)
        } else if (result.dismiss === swalWithBootstrapButtons.DismissReason.cancel) {
          this.androidCameraToggle = false
          let fileInput = this.$refs.file
          setTimeout(function(){ fileInput.click() }, 10)
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: when you are calling sourcePrompt?

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya sourcePrompt is called in the click attribute of a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.$nextTick()` api.

`nextTick(callback)` - The callback function will be executed after the next html update. So when you update a attribute of an html element. `nextTick` will be called after the html has finished updating. It's kind of like `mounted` hook but fired after every html update. So to fire your click event listener you have to pass it has callback of the `nextTick` function after you update the attribute value.

You can learn more about `nextTick` from the official [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick)